# Why I am unale to connect to my Atlas Cluster?

Tags: mongodb, dns, cluster-analysis, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-compass

I am learning basic course of MongoDatabase at Mongo University, and I am Unable to connect my own Cluster. 
Although I have named my cluster differently which is **StockMarketAnalysis**.

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://sandbox-xxxxx.mongodb.net/test"  --username m001-student --password m001-mongodb-basics
```

**Output I am getting**

```
DNSHostNotFound: Failed to look up service "":DNS name does not exist.
try 'mongo --help' for more information
```

After doing npm as one of given below answer

[image]

I am still not able to do it

Comment: You have to whitelist your connection ip address to conect to cluster.https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/whitelist-connection-ip-address/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem while following the instructions on MongoDB University.
The problem here is before running the following code you'll have to edit the xxxxx to the one found in your connection string. The following was just a generalized sandbox code.

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://sandbox-**xxxxx**.mongodb.net/test"  --username m001-student --password m001-mongodb-basics
```

It would be different for your own sandbox.It would be something like :

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://sandbox-**byutb**.mongodb.net/test" --username m001-student --password m001-mongodb-basics
```

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-33140). Ensure you are using the most recent MongoDB version.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to whitelist you ip address for that go to the mongodb website and do the following steps

1. Go to the security tab -> Network Access -> Then whitelist your IP
2. Then go to the security tab -> Database Access -> and delete your current user.
3. Create a new user by providing new username and password.
4. Provide that newly created username and password in the .env file or 
   mongoose.connect method

Then go to your text editor and open terminal. then provide below command for install .env

```
npm i dotenv
```

then go to your project folder and create .env file. After that get your mongodb connection string from mongodb website. paste the connection string on the .env file. then replace your username password and database name in the string.

connection string is something just like this

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@clusterX-xxxxx.mongodb.net/<database_name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

if you are using mongoose copy the below code line into the app.js or your index.js file

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_STRING, {useNewUrlParser : true, useUnifiedTopology : true, useCreateIndex : true, useFindAndModify : false}, (err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }else {
        console.log('DB Connected');
    }
});
```

Then run the app.js or index.js file if everything was success it will display DB Connected message in the console.

Comment: npm is not recognized as internal or external command @bathiya Can U redirect me

Comment: I hope you are using windows operating system? @SMEETKOTHARI

Comment: I have tried and updated my question still not working

Comment: Are you trying to connect mongodb with python backend? because the above answer i provided based on Node.js.

Comment: YES Exactly @bathiya

Comment: @SMEETKOTHARI i found this web site from the web https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-python-and-mongodb please try this and let me know